# Turn off Reference Information (Theosauraus) in Office 365

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, office365

When Outlook or Word thinks there is a spelling mistake, the word is highlighted with a red squiggle. Right-click the red squiggle and the spelling suggestions have additional reference information (see the image below).

[image: Reference information in Outlook]

Can this addition reference information be switched off so that only the spelling suggestion is displayed?

I checked in:

- File > Options > Mail > Proofing (Outlook)
- File > Options > Proofing (Word)

but was not able to find the relevant setting.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean these reference information("obligatory,needed, obliged" in the screenshoot)?

If so, based on my research and tests, I also have tried to check the revelant settings, there seems to no option that could change it in Outlook. It would also be displayed even if my mailbox "Work Offline". I guess these information is from system dictionary and is designed to work with spell checking, so we may not be albe to delete or disable it if we need to use spelling and autocorrect.

Comment: Thanks Jade, appreciated. However this should be a comment, please, since it does not answer the question either way.

Comment: You're welcome.Thanks for your kind reminding, I indeed would like to add a comment before, but the forum prompts "I must have 50 reputation to comment":(